# How do I count how many kids is present in different time intervals?

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with information of what time kids in a kindergarten is delivered and picked up. I want to count how many kids is present in time intervals of 30 minutes. So i.e how many kids are present 7.30-7.59 AM or from 16.00-16.29 PM.

In my dataset there is 18 children, but here is a small piece of it.
The problem is that I get the sum of 18 on every entry in the lists kommet_antal and afhentet_antal.

in the bottom I have written some code that works but it is really not that beautiful!

````
 [1] "08:09:00" "09:00:00" "07:37:00" "07:51:00"
 lst_afhentet
 [1] "15:38:00" "15:19:00" "15:56:00" "14:24:00"

W1M_antal <- for(i in 1:nrow(df_W1M)){      #W1m is the dataframe with week1 and mondays selected
  lst_kommet <- df_W1M$Kommet
  lst_afhentet <- df_W1M$Afhentet
  
  kommet_antal <- vector("list", 21)      #21 timeintervals, open from 6.30 to 17.00
  afhentet_antal <- vector("list", 21)
  
                            
  tid<- as.ITime("07:00")                  #initial start time, T1
  n <- 0
  for(k in 1:length(lst_kommet)){         #runs over when children is delivered
    if(k < tid){                          #If the time delivered is before time (tid), then count it
      n <- n + 1  
    } else n <- n
    for(t in 1:length(kommet_antal)){     #want to save number of kids delivered in the different intervals
      kommet_antal[t] <- n
    }
    
    tid = tid + as.ITime("00:30")     #add 30 min to the time so we have next time interval
  }
  
  tid <- as.ITime("07:00")            #Do the same for pick up
  m <- 0
  for(a in 1:length(lst_afhentet)){
    if(a < tid){
      m <- m + 1
    } else m <- m
    for(l in 1:length(afhentet_antal)){   #Save number of kids in intervals until they are picked up
      afhentet_antal[l] <- m
    }
    tid <- tid + as.ITime("00:30")
  }
}
tid
total_antal <- vector("list", 21)
total_antal <- as.numeric(kommet_antal) - as.numeric(afhentet_antal) 
total_antal



This code works, and give me the correct number, but with datasets from a year with 5 days per week it is going to take a long time to count number of kids present.



T1 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "07:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"07:00"))
T2 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "07:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"07:30"))
T3 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "08:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"08:00"))
T4 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "08:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"08:30"))
T5 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "09:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"09:00"))
T6 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "09:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"09:30"))
T7 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "10:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"10:00"))
T8 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "10:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"10:30"))
T9 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "11:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"11:00"))
T10 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "11:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"11:30"))
T11 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "12:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"12:00"))
T12 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "12:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"12:30"))
T13 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "13:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"13:00"))
T14 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "13:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"13:30"))
T15 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "14:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"14:00"))
T16 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "14:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"14:30"))
T17 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "15:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"15:00"))
T18 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "15:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"15:30"))
T19 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "16:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"16:00"))
T20 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "16:30")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"16:30"))
T21 <- count(subset(Mandag, Kommet < "17:00")) - count(subset(Mandag, Afhentet <"17:00"))

#Laver output i dataframe

W <- c(rep("Week1", 22*5), rep("Week2", 22*5), rep("Week3", 22*5), rep("Week4", 22*5))
D <- c(rep("Monday", 22*4), rep("Tuesday", 22*4), rep("Wednesday", 22*4), rep("Thursday", 22*4),rep("Friday", 22*4))
Time <- c(rep(1:22, 20))
Value1 <- c(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, rep(0,419))
Value <- do.call(rbind, Value1)

Output <- data.frame(W, D, Time, Value)
View(Output)  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package has a few helpful functions for this class of problems.

You do not have a reproducible example so my help will have to be generic, you can apply the principles to your situation.

Setting the context: Dates and times are very complicated in programming and R as well. You are checking whether a time falls between two endpoints for drop-off and pickup. The function `%within%` takes care of this type of operation. An example is `time_check %within% dropoff_pickup_intervals`. This will return TRUE for when the time check let's say `07:30` falls between the dropoff and pickup time of the student.

But we need the proper date and interval formats first. Here's some example code: (Note most of the code at first is to help create the example, the meat of the functions are lower)

```
library(lubridate)

# Make example data
# ----
# set seed for repeatable results for random processes
set.seed(20201023)

# set a time for start and ending for dropoffs and pickups using "ymd_hm" lubridate function
daystart <- ymd_hm("2020-01-01 07:00")
dayend <- ymd_hm("2020-01-01 16:00")

# Create a sequence of dates 
time_set <- seq(daystart, dayend, by="min")

# data frame sampling times from 
kinder <- data.frame(student_id=1:10,
                     dropoff=sample(time_set, 10),
                     pickup=sample(time_set, 10))

# remove dates that don't make sense
kinder <- kinder %>% filter(pickup > dropoff)
# --- Example data complete

# create time intervals for student arrival and leave times
dropoff_pickup <- interval(kinder$dropoff, kinder$pickup)

# Create sequence to check times every 30 minutes
time_checks <- seq(daystart, dayend, by="30 min")

# for every student check whether present at time checks
student_present <- sapply(k$intervals, function(x) time_checks %within% x)

# (Bonus: Make into a nice looking data frame)
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(student_present))
names(df1) <- substr(as.character(time_checks), 12, 16)
df1 <- cbind(k$id, df1)
df1
```

For more on [%within% function](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html), and [lubridate](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks..
I can run your example and it works, then I suppose I can run a count function to count the actual amount of kids being present in the different time intervals.

But I can´t run it on my data, I tried to change it but when i want to use the interval function, I get into problems. Even though my variables are of types character. The documentation says that should work - if I understand it correctly.